# Where is the FireBase doc for $other

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-security

I´m learning FireBase and now at [Using $ Variables to Capture Path Segments](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/security/securing-data)
' I read about the wildcard usage. I see they use this `$other`variable.
Where is a list documentation of all variables that FireBase uses in the RealTime Databas Rules?

Answer (score 2):

There is no $other variable. It's a placeholder and could be any string like $someOtherPath, or $dudesPath or $coolPath

From the [docs](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/security/securing-data):

```
{
  "rules": {
    "widget": {
      // a widget can have a title or color attribute
      "title": { ".validate": true },
      "color": { ".validate": true },

      // but no other child paths are allowed
      // in this case, $other means any key excluding "title" and "color"
      "$other": { ".validate": false }
    }
  }
}
```

The 'title' and 'color' paths are accounted for and have rules set.
$other is any path other than title or color. It could easily be

"$anyPathOtherThanTitleOrColor": { ".validate": false }

Comment: Good answer Jay. @Erik: you could change `$other` to `$anything` and the behavior would be exactly the same.

Comment: Anyone can see what`.validate": "newData.isString()"` do but this  `".validate": false` is not logical, in my brain :) - thanks for the lessen